# About Database Settings in Django Project

Tags: python, mysql, django, devstack

I want to set database setting in django project.

Which settings.py I should use.

I found many settings.py file.

I have setup devstack where many folders are there like horizon, cinder, nova etc.

I found settings.py in horizon folder.

and from when I setup Django I found in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/project_template/project_name folder.

Please make suggest which settings.py I should use and

I can access database by user root with no database name giving in MySql Workbench.

Which database connection I should use?

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'nova',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

Please help..

Comment: if horizon is the actual project name then may test have the settings.py file. Please alter that .. ! You may have to provide project structure for us to tell which settings.py file will use for django connection ... Yes .you have to create database name and password for the same

Comment: database is already created when i have setup devstack. but I have found many settings.py file in root directory. in horizon/horizon/ i did not find settings.py. I have found settings.py in horizon/horizon/test but this only one lines DATABASES = {'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql'}}. which settings.file I will find my desired text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to setup your DB in the settings.py file in horizon/openstack_dashboard folder .The DB name is devstack or any other name .All the django apps table will be created in a single DB

Comment: I didn't find settings.py in horizon folder. I found horizon/test then settings.py but there's only one line:    DATABASES = {'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql'}}

Comment: Please attach your project structure .

Comment: Thanks for response. I have got the solution. Its actually in Horizon/Openstack_dashboard folder. and it worked.